# fromEvent not triggering inside a Directive with 'change' but with 'click' yes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm pretty new to Angular and RxJS. I'm trying to listen for a change event on all mat-radio-group elements in a document. I can't understand why using the @HostListener I can catch the event and log it to the console but not using fromEvent

```
@Directive({selector: "mat-radio-group"})
export class RadioDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('change', ['$event'])
  onChange(event){
    console.log(event)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.element.nativeElement, 'change')
      .subscribe(event => console.log(event))
  }
}
```

I suspect is something related to the ElementRef but I don't really know what I'm missing. I've used fromEvent for others components and didn't have any problem catching events. I would like to mantain fromEvent because is great for manipulating events using .pipe()

**EDIT** 
If I swap the event with `click`, fromEvent works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the operator `fromEvent` expects a **DOM event**, so when you use the directive in a `mat-radio-group` Angular material returns an `EventEmitter<MatRadioChange>` so the operator does not trigger.

The [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api):

> @Output() change: EventEmitter
> Event emitted when the group value changes. Change events are only emitted when the value changes due to user interaction with a radio button (the same behavior as <input type-"radio">).

Using the click event does work because the `mat-radio-group` does not have any attribute `(click)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `input` event instead of `change`, like that:

```
@Directive({selector: "mat-radio-group"})
export class RadioDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('change', ['$event'])
  onChange(event){
    console.log(event)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.element.nativeElement, 'input')
      .subscribe(event => console.log(event))
  }
}
```

- It's better than `click` event and it's more like `change` event because it's trigging even at keyboard events et cetera

Comment: Thanks @oz1985oz (I know it's not recommended to thanks in the comments but I'm a noob and don't have enough reputatuion to upvote)